# Why is $[l_1]+[l_2]+[l_3]$ a constant in $CH_0(F(X))$, where $F(X)$ is the Fano variety of lines of a cubic fourfold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, chow-groups

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^5$ be a cubic fourfold and $F(X)$ be its Fano varieties of lines. Let $\mathbb P^2$ be a plane such that the intersection $\mathbb P^2\cap X$ consists of three lines $L_1,L_2,$ and $L_3$. It is clear that $[L_1]+[L_2]+[L_3]$ is constant in the Chow group $CH_1(X)$ of $X$ (i.e., it does not depend on the choice of $\mathbb P^2$).

> Why is $[L_1]+[L_2]+[L_3]$ a constant in $CH_0(F(X))$ of $F(X)$?

Comment: The family of $2$-planes in $\mathbb{P}^5$ is parameterized by the Grassmannian $\text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathbb{P}^5)$.  This is a rational variety.  Rational equivalence of cycles is the weakest equivalence relation stable for addition and that forms quotients by families of cycles parameterized by a rational variety.  So all of the cycles obtained by intersection with $\mathbb{P}^2$s (that are not contained in $X$) give the same cycle class in the Chow group.

Comment: Typo correction: "... and that forms quotients by families ..." --> "... and that factors through the quotient by all families ..."

Comment: @Jason Starr:  what you say proves that the sum is constant in $CH_1(X)$, but why in $CH_0(F(X))$?

Comment: @abx.  Good point -- I missed that the OP is asking about $\text{CH}_0(F(X))$.

Comment: Sorry again for my mistake above, and thanks to abx for noticing this.  I do not know the answer, but here is something interesting: the parameter space of triples of concurrent lines in $X$ is a conic bundle over a double cover of $X$.  If that double cover is a Fano manifold (probably a long shot), that might give a strategy to prove this.

Comment: ... I computed that the dualizing sheaf of the double cover is isomorphic to the structure sheaf of the double cover.  The double cover is singular along a curve, so there is some small possibility that a resolution has many rational curves.  However, it seems like this strategy probably will not work.

Comment: . . . Maybe that strategy is okay.  The locus $D$ of triples of coplanar, concurrent lines (the conic bundle over the fourfold that is a double cover of $X$) is itself a codimension $1$ subvariety of the parameter space $P$ of coplanar triples of lines.  It is a little tricky to compute because of the singularities, but a quick computation suggests that the normal bundle of $D$ in $X$ has positive degree on the conic fibers of the conic bundle.  If so, those conics deform to curves that intersect $D$.

Comment: @Jason Starr, thank you for your comments and a strategy, I will try to work it out.